# OS X Lion Printer problem

Tags: macos, printing

I have a clean install of Lion (I whipped the drive, then installed Snow Leopard and upgraded to Lion). Now I'm trying to add/install my network printer. It is a Brother HL-5350DN.

The automatic apple install fails telling me the apple service is unavailable. So I downloaded the drivers directly from the brother homepage. It installed fine, but when I try to add the Printer manually the list of available printer drivers is empty. So I added the printer driver by from /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents where I found a file that has the printers name and a .gz suffix. There are two versions one with CUPS in the name and one without.

I can choose it in the dialog (both versions) and there is no error, but when I try to print something the printer status tells me the printer is paused. Of course I tried to hit continue, but after a second it goes right back to paused.