# Canon printer always "busy"

Tags: macos, printing, settings

I have a Canon Pixma MX870 and I downloaded and installed drivers from [Canon's site](http://usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/pixma_mx_series/pixma_mx870?selectedName=DriversAndSoftware).

I've got it configured on two other macs in my house and it works fine.

When I tried to add the printer using the standard OS X on a new MBP, the preferences app doesn't automatically see the printer. I have added it via IP address and manually chosen the appropriate drivers.

So, the first question is -- **why didn't the mac see it properly?**

When I try to print, the job shows up in the local print queue, but then shows a message saying that "the printer is busy". I can printer from the other computers on my network without problem.

The second question is -- **what can I do about the "the printer is busy" message?** (I suspect if I resolve the first problem, this one will be a non-issue).

For what it's worth, I configured the printer on the other computers when they were running 10.6 (Snow Leopard), the new laptop is running 10.7 (Lion).

Comment: Sounds similar to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20094/os-x-lion-printer-problem

Comment: I suggest you go to the Print/Scan prefs pane and delete the printer, then add it again and let Lion find drivers online for you. Delete the print job in print monitor, then print again using new driver, the printer is busy message should be gone now.

Comment: Interesting idea... I had downloaded drivers first. I'll try this.

Answer (score 2):

Since there isn't an answer, I wanted to chime in.

Thanks to the comment, I can confirm deleting and re-adding the printer did the trick.